# How can i validate an elements existence by typing it into an input text field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**I have different id's on different elements that are used in an input field when the user can type in the letter (Element 1 = A, Element 2 = B.. Element 27 = AA). How can I properly scan these on input in order to determine if the element exists and if it does put it in a string that converts these id's to values which are later calculated?**

I have an id system on a calculator where the user can generate different element (sliders, radio buttons, check boxes) that can be calculated. They all have a numeric id which is the translated into alphabetic characters in a progressive order ( Element 1 = A, Element 2 = B.. Element 27 = AA). I later have an input field where the user can create their own formula that will be calculated and put into a result tab.

Sample Formula: A+B*2

The reason I translate to letter is so that the user can use numbers in creating the formula. I have succeed in making this work for id's that are one letter but as soon as the id's start hitting AA and AB it doesn't work because currently I split this into an array and scan every element for it's value, which becomes problematic for two letters since they split into two different id's.

I have tried splitting the array based on the operators (+, -, *, /) but that removes them from the array.

```
function resultCalcInit(resultObject, resultFormulaObject) {
  $('.createWrap').on('keyup input change', $(resultFormulaObject).find('.jvformbuilder-formula-panel-elements-result-field-formula'), function(e) {
    var thisKey = new RegExp(String.fromCharCode(e.which).toLowerCase());
    var keyNoRegEx = String.fromCharCode(e.which).toLowerCase();
    var counter = 0;
    var letters = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/;
    for (var call of $('.dropzone').find('.builder-elements')) {
      if ($(call).find('.bf-number')[0]) {
        var operators = ['»', '½', '/', '¿'];
        if (String.fromCharCode(e.which) == $(call).find('.bf-number').attr("data-calcId").toUpperCase() || $.isNumeric(String.fromCharCode(e.which)) || wordInString(String.fromCharCode(e.which), operators)) {
          counter++;
        } else {}
      } else if ($(call).find('.builder-list')[0]) {
        var operators = ['»', '½', '/', '¿'];
        if (String.fromCharCode(e.which) == $(call).find('.builder-list').attr("data-calcId").toUpperCase() || $.isNumeric(String.fromCharCode(e.which)) || wordInString(String.fromCharCode(e.which), operators)) {
          counter++;
        } else {}
      } else if ($(call).find('.builder-radio')[0]) {
        var operators = ['»', '½', '/', '¿'];
        if (String.fromCharCode(e.which) == $(call).find('.builder-radio').attr("data-calcId").toUpperCase() || $.isNumeric(String.fromCharCode(e.which)) || wordInString(String.fromCharCode(e.which), operators)) {
          counter++;
        } else {}
      } else if ($(call).find('.builderSlider')[0]) {
        var operators = ['»', '½', '/', '¿'];
        if (String.fromCharCode(e.which) == $(call).find('.builderSlider').attr("data-calcId").toUpperCase() || $.isNumeric(String.fromCharCode(e.which)) || wordInString(String.fromCharCode(e.which), operators)) {
          counter++;
        } else {}
      } else if ($(call).find('.builder-checkboxes')[0]) {
        var operators = ['»', '½', '/', '¿'];
        if (String.fromCharCode(e.which) == $(call).find('.builder-checkboxes').attr("data-calcId").toUpperCase() || $.isNumeric(String.fromCharCode(e.which)) || wordInString(String.fromCharCode(e.which), operators)) {
          counter++;
        } else {}
      }
    }
    if (String.fromCharCode(e.which).match(letters) && counter < 1) {
      $(resultFormulaObject).find('.jvformbuilder-formula-panel-elements-result-field-formula').html($(resultFormulaObject).find('.jvformbuilder-formula-panel-elements-result-field-formula').html().replace(thisKey, ""));
      var returnString = $(resultFormulaObject).find('.jvformbuilder-formula-panel-elements-result-field-formula').text();
      $('#jvformbuilder-formula-panel').find('.jvformbuilder-formula-panel-elements').each(function() {
        var formulaResultId = $(this).find('.jvformbuilder-formula-panel-elements-result-field-formula');
        $('.builder-elements').each(function() {
          if (formulaResultId.attr("id") == $(this).find('.result-number').attr("id")) {
            var resultWindow = $(this).find('.result-number');
            var formula = returnString.slice(1);
          }
        });
      });
    } else {
      resultCalc(resultFormulaObject);
    }
  });
}
```

Here it check if the letter typed is an existing ID. If it isn't, it's removed. If it is, it stays and proceeds to be scanned for the value.

```
function resultCalc(resultFormulaObject) {
  var returnString = $(resultFormulaObject).find('.jvformbuilder-formula-panel-elements-result-field-formula').text();
  $('#jvformbuilder-formula-panel').find('.jvformbuilder-formula-panel-elements').each(function() {
    var formulaResultId = $(this).find('.jvformbuilder-formula-panel-elements-result-field-formula');
    $('.builder-elements').each(function() {
      if (formulaResultId.attr("id") == $(this).find('.result-number').attr("id")) {
        var resultWindow = $(this).find('.result-number');
        var formula = returnString.slice(1).split("");
        var formulaNbr = returnString.slice(1).split("");
        var alphabet = ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz").split("");
        var calculationArray = returnString.slice(1).split("");
        var tempArr = formula;
        for (var i = 0; i < formula.length; i++) {
          $('.builder-elements').each(function() {
            if ($(this).find('.builder-list').attr("data-calcid") == formula[i]) {
              formulaNbr[i] = $(this).find('.builder-list').children("option:selected").val();
              calculationArray[i] = "parseInt(ID" + alphabet.indexOf(formula[i]) + ").value)";
            } else if ($(this).find('.builder-field').attr("data-calcid") == formula[i]) {
              if ($(this).find('.bf-text')[0]) {
                console.log(tempArr);
                if (tempArr.indexOf(tempArr[i]) == 0) {
                  tempArr.splice(i, 2);
                  calculationArray.splice(i, 2);
                } else {
                  tempArr.splice(i - 1, 2);
                  calculationArray.splice(i - 1, 2);
                }
                var formulaString = "";
                for (var j = 0; j < formula.length; j++) {
                  formulaString += tempArr[j];
                }
                formulaResultId.empty();
                formulaResultId.html("=" + formulaString);
              } else if ($(this).find('.bf-telNum')[0]) {
                if (tempArr.indexOf(tempArr[i]) == 0) {
                  tempArr.splice(i, 2);
                  calculationArray.splice(i, 2);
                } else {
                  tempArr.splice(i - 1, 2);
                  calculationArray.splice(i - 1, 2);
                }
                var formulaString = "";
                for (var j = 0; j < formula.length; j++) {
                  formulaString += tempArr[j];
                }
                formulaResultId.empty();
                formulaResultId.html("=" + formulaString);
              } else if ($(this).find('.bf-date')[0]) {
                if (tempArr.indexOf(tempArr[i]) == 0) {
                  tempArr.splice(i, 2);
                  calculationArray.splice(i, 2);
                } else {
                  tempArr.splice(i - 1, 2);
                  calculationArray.splice(i - 1, 2);
                }
                var formulaString = "";
                for (var j = 0; j < formula.length; j++) {
                  formulaString += tempArr[j];
                }
                formulaResultId.empty();
                formulaResultId.html("=" + formulaString);
              } else if ($(this).find('.bf-number')[0]) {
                if (!$(this).find('.bf-number').val()) {
                  formulaNbr[i] = 0;
                } else {
                  formulaNbr[i] = $(this).find('.bf-number').val();
                }
                calculationArray[i] = "parseInt(ID" + alphabet.indexOf(formula[i]) + ").value)";
              }
            } else if ($(this).find('.builder-textarea').attr("data-calcid") == formula[i]) {
              if (tempArr.indexOf(tempArr[i]) == 0) {
                tempArr.splice(i, 2);
                calculationArray.splice(i, 2);
              } else {
                tempArr.splice(i - 1, 2);
                calculationArray.splice(i - 1, 2);
              }
              var formulaString = "";
              for (var j = 0; j < formula.length; j++) {
                formulaString += tempArr[j];
              }
              formulaResultId.empty();
              formulaResultId.html("=" + formulaString);
            } else if ($(this).find('.builder-radio').attr("data-calcid") == formula[i]) {
              var resultRadio = [];
              $(this).find('.builder-radio-input').each(function(i) {
                resultRadio[i] = parseInt($(this).val());
              });
              var sum = resultRadio.reduce(add);
              formulaNbr[i] = sum;
              calculationArray[i] = "parseInt(ID" + alphabet.indexOf(formula[i]) + ").value)";
            } else if ($(this).find('.builder-checkboxes').attr("data-calcid") == formula[i]) {
              var resultCheck = [];
              $(this).find('.builderCB').each(function(i) {
                resultCheck[i] = parseInt($(this).val());
              });
              var sum = resultCheck.reduce(add);
              formulaNbr[i] = sum;
              calculationArray[i] = "parseInt(ID" + alphabet.indexOf(formula[i]) + ").value)";
            } else if ($(this).find('.builderSlider').attr("data-calcid") == formula[i]) {
              formulaNbr[i] = $(this).find('.builder-slider').val();
              calculationArray[i] = "parseInt(ID" + alphabet.indexOf(formula[i]) + ").value)";
            }
          });
        }
        var calculationString = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < calculationArray.length; i++) {
          calculationString += calculationArray[i];
        }
        returnString = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < formulaNbr.length; i++) {
          returnString += formulaNbr[i];
        }
        if (returnString) {
          printRes(returnString, resultWindow, calculationString);
        }
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Here it takes different values from the different objects that relates to the id written inside the formula tab. Later it is printed into the result tab.

```
function printRes(resString, resArea, calcString) {
  resArea.empty();
  var result = eval(resString);
  if (!result) {
    resArea.append(0)
    resArea.attr("data-calcForm", "");
  } else {
    resArea.append(result)
    resArea.attr("data-calcForm", calcString);
  }
}
```

It completely crashes if the id becomes doubled. That's where I need you guys to help me. How can I make it scan after double characters id's as well as single ones, and triple ones and how ever many the user decides to generate.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to reproduce the issue you have from the big code bunch you posted. And I have to admit that what you try to achieve is unclear to me.

But what is really clear is that you need to segregate the formula's elements from the operator. You can achieve this with 2 regexes. I see you already use the first one: `/[0-9a-zA-Z]+/`, but I don't get how you use it...

Anyway, here is a real simple demo showing that you can have two arrays, one for the formula's elements and the other for the operators. Once you have that, you should be able to use it to do whatever you wish to.

```js
$("button").on("click",function(){
  
  // The input value
  var input_val = $("input").val();
  
  // Regexes
  var elements_regex = /[0-9a-zA-Z]+/g;
  var operators_regex = /[\+\-*\/]/g;
  
  // Create the arrays
  var elements_array = input_val.match(elements_regex);  
  var operators_array = input_val.match(operators_regex);
  
  // Needed just for this demo
  var regex_validation = $(".regex_validation");
  var elements = $(".elements");
  var operators = $(".operators");
  
  // RESULTS
  // Regex validation
  for(i=0;i<elements_array.length;i++){
    // Element
    if(typeof(elements_array[i])!="undefined"){
      regex_validation.append("<span class='element'>"+elements_array[i]+"<span>");
    }
    // Operator
    if(typeof(operators_array[i])!="undefined"){
      regex_validation.append("<span class='operator'>"+operators_array[i]+"<span>");
    }
  }
  
  // Elements
  elements.html(JSON.stringify(elements_array));
  // Operators
  operators.html(JSON.stringify(operators_array));
});
```

```css
.result{
  height: 50px;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.element{
  background: cyan;
}
.operator{
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Enter your formula: <input value="AA+B*2"><button type="button">Check</button><br>
<br>
Regex validation: (cyan for elements, yellow for operators)
<div class="result regex_validation"></div>
<br>
Elements array:
<div class="result elements"></div>
<br>
Operators array:
<div class="result operators"></div>
<br>
```

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/Pgjgme)